# How to get all the events between start and end times using cloudtrail's lookup_events in boto3 without specifying MaxResults?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, boto, amazon-cloudtrail

I'm trying to fetch **AWS cloudtrail** events for a particular user using `boto3`.

[CloudTrail client](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudtrail.html#CloudTrail.Client.lookup_events)

I'm using `cloudtrail` client and `lookup_events()` function.
I can specify the `StartTime` and `EndTime` between which I need to get the results.

But I might have number events between that `StartTime` and `EndTime`. If I don't provide `MaxResults` filter for `lookup_events()`, it is returning `50` events by default.

```
response = client.lookup_events(
    LookupAttributes=[
        {
            'AttributeKey':'Username',
            'AttributeValue': 'user1'
        },
    ],
    StartTime=datetime(2019, 12, 31),
    EndTime=datetime(2020, 1, 1),
    MaxResults=123
)
```

If I need to get `MaxResults`, I need to actually mention `MaxResults` which is not what I want.

I want to fetch all the events between the `StartTime` and `EndTime`.

Is there any way that I can skip `MaxResults` param and the `lookup_events()` function fetches all the events between `StartTime` and `EndTime` no matter how many events are there in that duration and how long it's gonna take to send the response?

If I specify `MaxResults` as more than `1000`, I'm getting an error saying that it should bet= in range `1` and `1000`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't get more than the max allowable results in a single API call. You have to use pagination.

The boto3 SDK provides pagination function for you, however, so see the [LookupEvents paginator](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudtrail.html#CloudTrail.Paginator.LookupEvents).